# DCount not working on Access

Tags: ms-access, dcount

I don´t know whats wrong with this query... I want to know how many records are on another query named: `Querie_Planilla` that have the following characteristics:

1. The date on the field `PeriodoInicial` has to be greater or equal to the date `[FechaInicio]` but a year ago
2. The date on the field `PeriodoFinal` has to be smaller to the value `[FechaInicio]` *(Both of this conditions consider the first day of the month in* `FechaInicio`
3. It has to have the same ID im looking for: `PlazaID = [Vacaciones]![PlazaID]`

Here is the code:

```
DCount("PlazaID","Querie_Planilla","PeriodoInicial >= #" & DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",[FechaInicio])-1,
DatePart("m",[FechaInicio]),1) & "# AND PeriodoFinal < #" & DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",[FechaInicio]),
DatePart("m",[FechaInicio]),1) & "# AND PlazaID = '" & [Vacaciones]![PlazaID] & "'")
```

Right now its returning 0 but at least i have 3 for each ID

Comment: Run the equivalent SQL query and check rows: `SELECT PlazaID FROM Querie_Planilla WHERE PeriodoInicial >= #" & DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",[FechaInicio])-1,
DatePart("m",[FechaInicio]),1) & "# AND PeriodoFinal < #" & DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",[FechaInicio]),
DatePart("m",[FechaInicio]),1) & "# AND PlazaID = '" & [Vacaciones]![PlazaID] & "'"` Update accordingly if date functions point to form fields.

Comment: It doesn´t run with the apostrophes, but when I quit them it does run! Do I need to take them off in my original query?

Comment: Again, be sure to fix the `Forms!formname!...` to the referenced controls. Also, remove ampersands (`&`) and single/double quotes. Please post some data for reproducible example and advise where *[FechaInicio]*, *[Vacaciones]* derive.